# How to play CSS Animation from a certain webpage

Tags: css, css-animations

fairly new to Web Development so bear with me. I currently have 3 webpages: `Home, Portfolio and Contact`. The `Home` page has a background covering half the page; `Portfolio and Contact` have the same background but it only covers a quarter of the page.

I want the Background to animate 'up' when moving from `Home` to `Portfolio`, or `Contact`; and the Background to animate 'down' when moving from `Portfolio` or `Contact` to `Home`. No animation should take place between `Portfolio` and `Contact`.

I have managed to get the Background successfully animating 'up' when the `Portfolio` or `Contact` pages load, and 'down' when the `Home` page loads with the following CSS:

```
//Home Page
body { background: #fbfbfb url("../gallery_gen/33123835311a4a19ce0578c280449a50.png") no-repeat scroll center top; 
    animation: bgSlideOut 1s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bgSlideOut {
    from { background-position: 0 -370px; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}



//Portfolio and Contact Pages
body { background: #fbfbfb url("../gallery_gen/33123835311a4a19ce0578c280449a50.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
    animation: bgSlideOut 1s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bgSlideOut {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 0 -370px; }
}
```

However the `Portfolio` animation will play when moving from `Contact` to `Portfolio` and vice versa. Is there any way I can make the animation play only when moving from `Home` to `Portfolio/Contact` and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

The transition CSS is good, but does not answer the core question - how do these pages know whether or not to run the transition? They need to know which page the user "came from". That information must be passed to the page. CSS alone won't know browser history.

Not knowing your setup (3 static HTML pages? single page app, JSP/PHP) you need to determine how the "home" page can communicate this to these pages - through it's links to them (querystring), UI logic tracking "history" in same DOM, or through session handling on the server passing along the data.

So either in page initialization JS, or JSP/PHP layer, you would then conditionally add a CSS "hook" like a class on the body tag that applies the transition CSS when coming from the Home page, and omit that class when coming from the other content page.

Answer (score 0):

Using an animation is not the correct approach for this situation.

Just use

```
transition: background-position 1s;
```

and set the  different background-position values in the different classes

Answer (score 0):

you would have to set those css animations as different classes and you should you use a script to target and toggle the classes, then you should link the scripts to an anchor tag

```
<a href="/portfolio.com" id="portfolio" onclick="animate">Portfolio</a>
<style>
@keyframes bgSlideOut {
    from { background-position: 0 -370px; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@keyframes bgSlideOut2 {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 0 -370px; }
}
</style>
<script>
function animate(){
var target = document.getElementById('portfolio');
 if(target.className == bgSlideOut)
{
target.className = bgSlideOut2;
}
}
</script>
```